# Jasmine: How to test method containing a declared variable

Tags: angular, jasmine, ionic2

I'm working on an Angular2/Ionic2 App. I am trying to test a method that looks somewhat like this:

```
goToFoo(id : number) {

  let result = this.someService.initialize();
  if (result.hasError == false) {
  switch (result.startPage) {

    case START_PAGES.OTHER_PAGE:

      this._nav.setRoot(OtherPage);
      break;

    case START_PAGES.FOO:

      this._nav.setRoot(FooPage);
      break;

    default:
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

I get this error, pointing to the 'if' statement: `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'result.hasError')`

Here is what I have tried:

```
const mockResult = {
    hasError(){}
}

it("should open foo page", inject((omitted)) => {
    spyOn(mockResult, "hasError");
    const mockId = 123;
    const fooCall = Page.goToFoo(mockId);

    expect(mockResult.hasError).toHaveBeenCalled();  
    expect(fooCall).toEqual(this._nav.setRoot(FooPage));
}));
```

I suspect that there's a better way to test methods that initialize and use variables. I am not connecting mockResult to 'result' correctly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you test functions/methods you can only test that some input (parameters) results in some expected output (return value). You can't test internal state of these functions/methods. You can test side effects the execution of this function has outside the function. For example if you assign a variable to `this.state = this.someService.initalize()` then you can test whether `this.state` has a value after the function is completed.

Comment: I don't really want to test the internal state, but the test error is preventing me from testing anything else. `result` in `let result = this.someService.initialize();` isn't recognizable by the test code, it is undefined

Comment: Then you need to provide some mock `SomeService` to make it work. Otherwise you won't be able to test it.

Comment: It is being provided but I don't know what to do with it after that. I was thinking something like `const testResult= SomeService.initialize();
    expect(testResult).toHaveBeenCalled(); ` but that doesn't affect the error because `result` is still undefined

Comment: You need to set up your test so that `this.someService` is available in `goToFoo()` when it is called. I guess you need `overrideProviders` when you create the component using `TestComponentBuilder`